Store range of values in IndexedDB and query by one value
I want to store list of events in IndexedDB. Each event has start date and end date. Then I need to query today events. I store dates as ISO strings (e. g. 2024-09-15), so string comparison makes sense.
In SQL it would be something like this:
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startDate >= $1 AND endDate <= $1

But in IndexedDB you cannot make queries so freely.
I'm wondering if there a possibility to either create a composite index and use IDBKeyRange (composite indices aren't really well documented) or create some generated field that includes both start and end dates and somehow do ranged queries for it.

strings are compared lexicographically, indexeddb supports storing dates and numbers, i suggest using dates
